# Another linear algebra proof by induction

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

Given for $m \times n$ matrices $A$ and $B$, we write $A \geq B$ if $(A)_{i j} \geq(B)_{i j}$ for all $1 \leq i \leq m$ and $1 \leq j \leq n$. Analogous definitions apply to $A \leq B, A>B$ and $A<B$. For a sequence of $m \times n$ matrices, we write $\lim _{t \rightarrow \infty} B_{t}=B$ if $\lim _{t \rightarrow \infty}\left(B_{t}\right)_{i j}=(B)_{i j}$ for all $1 \leq i \leq m$ and $1 \leq j \leq n$.

I need to solve the following:

Let $\lambda \in(0,1),$ let $\mathbf{r} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be given by $r_{i}=1$ for all $1 \leq i \leq n,$ and let $A \geq O$ be an $n \times n$ matrix. Prove by induction that if $A \mathbf{r} \leq \lambda \mathbf{r}$ then $A^{t} \mathbf{r} \leq \lambda^{t} \mathbf{r}$ for all $t \in \mathbb{N}$.

This is what I have done:

Let $\lambda \in(0,1)$ and let $r \in R^{n}$ be given by $r_{i}=1 \forall 1 \leq i \leq n$
and let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix

Let $P(t)$ be the statement such that

$P(t): A^{t} r \leq \lambda^{t} r$ when $A r \leq \lambda r$

For $t=1$ the above statement is true.

Now, Assume that result is true for $t=k$

$\therefore P(k): A^{k} r \leq \lambda^{k} r$ when $A r \leq \lambda r \ldots$ (1)

Now, we will prove result for $n=k+1$

Let $A r \leq \lambda r$

Now,
$$
A^{k+1} r=A\left(A^{k} r\right) \leq A \lambda^{k} r
$$(equation 1)
$$
\begin{array}{r}
=\lambda^{k} A r \\
\leq \lambda^{k} \lambda r \\
=\lambda^{k+1} r \\
\Rightarrow A^{k+1} r \leq \lambda^{k+1} r
\end{array}
$$
$\therefore P(t)$ is true $t=k+1$ and hence from principal of mathematical induction $P(t)$ is true for all $t \in N$.

Would this be correct?

Comment: I can think of at least two "analogous" definitions for $A>B$: (i) $A\ge B$ and $A\ne B$, (ii) $a_{jk}>b_{jk}$ for all $j,k$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Sorry I just realised I forgot to add 'Would this be correct?'. Based on my working, have I answered the question correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct, but need to be more detailed. Maybe you could state more about that if vector $x\leq y$, matrix $A\geq O$, then $Ax\leq Ay$ (although this statement is a little obvious).

Comment: Awesome. That makes sense. Thank you :)